# Reusage of Content with inline styles in umbraco

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-blog

Currently I have my desktop site in umbraco4. The content has inline styles, HTML tags, CSS class names. I am planning to develop a mobile site with same content.

My mobile layout is different from desktop layout so how can I reuse the same content but have a website that looks different on mobile to desktop.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. It may be worth deleting it and rewording it into a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use media queries in your css (http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) you can target sections of your templates to appear differently on an iphone or ipad or desktop or whatever.  You can also hide certain parts.

Another solution is to have an entirely different template for each 'view' eg one for desktop, one for mobile etc - and then use ?alttemplate=xxxx or using the PreInit of default.aspx.cs to switch to the appropriate media template.